# How to properly get the results from subprocess.run()?

Tags: python, subprocess, ping

I am sorry to ask again about this, but I have been unable to find a way to eliminate a false positive that keeps happening.

When I get a reply "Destination unreachable" reply it's showing all packets returned and 0 packets lost... so its showing SERVER UP instead of down.

how on gods earth can I get around this?

```
# Server up/down Script

# - Module Import section
import socket
import sys
import os
import subprocess

# - IP Address input request
hostname1 = input (" Please Enter IP Address: ")

# - Command to run ping request, but also hides ping info
response = subprocess.run(["ping", "-c", "1", hostname1], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
response.returncode

#___ ORIGINAL CODE ___
#if (response == "Reply from", hostname1):
if response.returncode == 0:
    print ( 50 * "-")
    print ("[ **SERVER IS ALIVE** ]")
    print ( 50 * "-")
elif response.returncode == 0 and (str("Destination host unreachable.")):
    print( 50 * "-")
    print(hostname1, "[ **SERVER DOWN** ] ")
    print( 50 * "-")
else:
    print( 50 * "-")
    print(hostname1, "[ **SERVER DOWN** ] ")
    print( 50 * "-")
```

Comment: You're not comparing `"Destination host unreachable"` to anything.

Comment: Shouldn't the `elif` say `!= 0`? The `0` code was already handled by the `if` block.

Comment: There's no need to call `str()`, `"Destination host unreachable"` is already a string.

Comment: You need to read from the pipe and test whether the output contains that stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `(str("Destination host unreachable.")` you have in your code will always evaluate to `True`—the truthiness of any non-empty string.

If you want to see whether a specific string is in the `stdout` output produced by an invoked subprocess, you would need to use an expression something like this:

```
("Destination host unreachable." in response.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

after the `response = subprocess.run(...)` call.

Here's an [article](https://pymotw.com/3/subprocess/index.html#capturing-output) describing how to use the `subprocess` module (note especially the [Capturing Output](https://pymotw.com/3/subprocess/index.html#module-subprocess) section.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Capturing the output was my next plan of attack... but still being a newbie I was trawling through the net to find out how.

Comment: I understood what you had said and that the stdout was already being captured, but I wanted to learn about how it worked first so I understand how it worked. Anyway, I have learned enough to get the code to work and to get the correct response, even when "Destination unreachable" is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
# - Import section - below are the modules I will need to call for this script
import socket
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import ctypes
import ipaddress

# - User input request for IP or hostanme
hostname1 = input (" Please Enter IP Address: ")

ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(hostname1)

# Configure subprocess to hide the console window
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '500', str(hostname1)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=info).communicate()[0]

if "Destination host unreachable" in output.decode('utf-8'):
    print ( 50 * "-")
    print (ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, hostname1 +  " [ SERVER OFFLINE ] ", " *** SERVER STATUS - ALERT *** ", 0))
    print ( 50 * "-")
elif "Request timed out" in output.decode('utf-8'):
    print( 50 * "-")
    print(ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, hostname1 + " [ SERVER OFFLINE ] ", "*** SERVER STATUS - ALERT ***", 0))
    print( 50 * "-")
else:
    print( 50 * "-")
    print(ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, hostname1 + " *** SERVER ALIVE *** ", "** SERVER STATUS - ALERT **", 0))
    print( 50 * "-")


#------------------------------------------------------
```